# Is $f(x)=\sqrt{(1+x^2)}$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ a contraction mapping?

Tags: calculus, inequality, lipschitz-functions

We take $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then I say :

$\mid \sqrt{(1+x^2)} - \sqrt{(1+y^2)} \mid$ $\le$ $\mid 1+\sqrt{x^2} - 1-\sqrt{y^2} \mid$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $\mid \sqrt{(1+x^2)} - \sqrt{(1+y^2)} \mid$ $\le$ $\mid \sqrt{x^2} - \sqrt{y^2} \mid$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $\mid \sqrt{(1+x^2)} - \sqrt{(1+y^2)} \mid$ $\le$ $\mid \mid{x} \mid - \mid{y} \mid \mid$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $\mid \sqrt{(1+x^2)} - \sqrt{(1+y^2)} \mid$ $\le$ $\mid \mid{x} \mid - \mid{y} \mid \mid$ $\le$ $\mid x-y \mid$

Which means that $k=1$?

So $f$ is not a contraction mapping.
Does it work ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your proof does not work: you just said that your proof attempt did not succeed. For a real argument, see Julian's answer.

Comment: @mookid Yes I agree but I just don't understand why it's not a valid proof

Comment: you just proved that 1 was a Lipschitz coefficient. Not that it was the smallest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were a contraction mapping, it would have a fixed point. What are the solutions of $\sqrt{1+x^2}=x$?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use $\frac{|\sqrt{1+x^2}-1|}{|x-0|}=\frac{|x|}{|\sqrt{1+x^2}+1|}\to 1$ as $x \to \infty$ to argue there doesn't exist $0\leq k<1$ satisfying the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

It's not too hard to show that 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (f(n+1)-f(n))=1$$

Thus there can be no $k<1$ such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\le k|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.